# Magento2: Success/Failure messages not auto hiding

Tags: magento2, messages

I'm using magento 2.1.1 on php 7 and facing issue that success/failure messages not auto hiding. They always showing on each page at the top.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: any fix for this?

Comment: really stuck into this. couldn't figure out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

File: `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages": "Vendor_Module/js/view/messages",
        }
    }
}
```

File: `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, _, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: []
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500)
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
});
```

Clear cache.

Please [**refer this thread**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156844/hide-messages-after-certain-interval) for more details.