# Hide messages after certain interval

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs, messages

How to `hide notification messages` like success message after adding product to cart or any error messages or notices after few seconds after they appear on the the frontend using `knockout js`.


Example : When I am adding a product in the cart, a success message appear saying "product has been added to your cart". I want to hide this success message after 5 seconds after it appear on the screen.

Answer (score 15):

Try following way:

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages": "Vendor_Module/js/view/messages",
        }
    }
}
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, _, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: []
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500)
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
});
```

Clear cache.

Comment: I have tried and it is not showing any message at all.

Comment: Delete pub/static/*, clear cache. Run setup:static-content:deploy.

Comment: I have tried after cleaning the pub/static and executing the command setup:static-content:deploy , but still no effect. I have added alert in the initialize function but it is not alerting at all. I guess js file is not included properly. It would be great if you can share if anything else is required as well.

Comment: For my case, I use SR_StackExchange is module name. And it's working fine with luma theme.

Comment: I have checked on different machine and the code seems to be working. Thanks for your answer. One more thing that I want to know is, what is the purpose of parameters 'blind' and {} in hide function.

Comment: @AnshuMishra I suspect it's a jQuery effect - https://api.jqueryui.com/blind-effect/. Not 100% sure though

Comment: @SohelRana it's only working at once after for second message it is not working as expected. Have you any suggestion?

Comment: It works only for first time, second time no messages are displayed.

Comment: @DEEPJOSHI,did you got any solution?

Comment: @PrashantValanda,how you resolve that issue" it's only working at once after for second message"?

Comment: To all who are saying this works only for first message. This is not the expected solution. This timeout is initiated on page load itself. Message element is hidden after 5 seconds. Irrespective of add to cart action, the message is hidden after 5 seconds of page load. Does anyone have solution to hide once message is show?

Comment: Thank you @SohelRana, it worked fine

Answer (score 4):

Please try the below solution and it works for me and I hope it will also work for you.

Please add the below code in the requirejs-config.js file to override the message js file.

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages": "Vendor_Module/js/view/messages",
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new message Js file in your module or you can also override directly by adding the same file in your theme directory.

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            
        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            $(".messages").show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 500)
            }, 5000);
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
        
    });
});
```

I have tested this in 2.3.5 and it seems to be working fine.

Please let me know if you need more details.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages': {
                '[Your_Module]/js/view/messages-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

messages-mixin.js

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (_, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.messages.subscribe(function (messages) {
                if (_.isEmpty(messages.messages)) {
                    return;
                }

                setTimeout(function () {
                    customerData.set('messages', {});
                }, 5000);
            });
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @rangerz. It is working in Magento 2.4.3, too.

Answer (score 0):

we can do it from js mixin

in you custom module view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/view/messages': {
                'NameSpace_Module/js/messages-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

messages-mixin.js

```
 define([
        'jquery'
    ], function($) {
        'use strict';
        return function(targetModule) {
            return targetModule.extend({
                onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
                var self = this;

                // Hide message block if needed
    //            if (isHidden) {
    //                setTimeout(function () { 
    //                    $(self.selector).hide('blind', {}, 500);
    //                }, 30000);                
    //            }
                }
            });
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a mixin as Kumar said but do not extend the Magento_Ui messages since those are for checkout etc but extend Magento_Theme messages.js. The full code is as follow.

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages': {
                'Bemeir_General/js/mixin/messages-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

messages-mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _) {
    'use strict';
    return function (targetModule) {

        targetModule.defaults.isHidden = false;
        targetModule.defaults.listens.isHidden = 'onHiddenChange';
        targetModule.defaults.selector = '.page.messages .messages';

        return targetModule.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                let original = this._super();
                console.log(targetModule.defaults);
                return original;
            },
            initObservable: function () {
                this._super()
                    .observe('isHidden');

                return this;
            },

            isVisible: function () {
                return this.isHidden(!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages) || !_.isEmpty(this.cookieMessages));
            },

            removeAll: function () {
                $(this.selector).find('.message').removeClass('show');
            },

            onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
                let self = this;
                if (isHidden) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(self.selector).find('.message').removeClass('show');
                        self.isHidden('false');
                    }, 5000);
                }
            }
        });
    };

});
```

Make sure to enlarge the timeout 5 secs it to low for customer to actually notice it and maybe click on the message etc.

Hope this will help someone. Also those who are interested please read this. https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-understanding-the-uielement-observe/