# Success message won't disappear in the home page Magento 2

Tags: magento2

When I try to use the **LUMA Theme**, the success message is working properly, but when I use the **custom theme**, that's where the problem starts. The **success message accumulates** in the home page whenever I try to add a product to the compare list. I'm using **Magento 2.1.3**. See the picture below:

[image]

Comment: enable the cache , and this won't come again and again

Comment: Upgrade to the Magento latest version, and enjoy Magento,  enabling or disabling the cache as per your requirement.

Comment: All the cache types from the Cache Management grid are enabled already.

Answer (score 0):

FOr notification hide issue you may refer below attached link
refer [Hide messages after certain interval](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156844/hide-messages-after-certain-interval)

Comment: Link is not working??

Answer (score -1):

This is because of Magento caches are disabled. Please check again after enabling caches. This problem appears only when caches are disabled.

Comment: All the cache types from the Cache Management grid are enabled already.