# Magento 2 : How to Hide all messages after certain time

Tags: magento2, template, jquery, messages

Hi i have extended the messages.js by adding the following code

```
define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'underscore',
'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        cookieMessages: [],
        messages: []
    },

    /**
     * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
     */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
        this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
            disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
        });

        // Force to clean obsolete messages
        if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
            customerData.set('messages', {});
        }

        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".messages").hide('blind', {}, 900)
        }, 9000);           
    }
});
```

});

No messages are showing up after adding the above jquery in messages.js

Please help me in fixing the above issue.

Comment: please try this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156844/hide-messages-after-certain-interval

Comment: @Naveen tried the same, but still no messages are showing up after applying the code.

Comment: @Vinay have you got anywhere with this, i am trying to do this