# How to hide magento 2.2 messages after a time has passed?

Tags: magento2.2.6, messages, success-message

I want to remove the success notification message with animation included, trying with below code with no success:

```
define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'underscore',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, _, customerData) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({

    defaults: {
        cookieMessages: [],
        messages: [],
        selector: '.page.messages .message'
    },
    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
        this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
            disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
        });

        if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
            customerData.set('messages', {});
        }

        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
        this.RemoveMessageAfterTime;
    },

    initObservable: function () {
        this._super();

        return this;
    },

    RemoveMessage: function () {

        var el = $(this.selector);

        el.toggleClass('bounceInRight bounceOutRight');
    },

    RemoveMessageAfterTime: function() {
        var el = $(this.selector);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.page.messages .message').toggleClass('bounceInRight bounceOutRight');
        }, 6000);
    }

});

});
```

> *Messages.phtml*

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
<div data-bind="click: RemoveMessage">
    <div role="alert" data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'bounceInRight animated message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div class="text" data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            <div class="close" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="alert" data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'bounceInRight animated message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div class="text" data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            <div class="close" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                    "messages": {
                        "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: you can get a reference from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156852/55928) for hiding messages

Comment: You can accompolish this by jquery. Please see if this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176402/how-to-hide-flash-message-after-few-seconds

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, compatible with ko.js for magento 2.2.6:

Reading this helped: https://www.interactiv4.com/blog-es/ocultar-automaticamente-los-mensajes-magento-2-codehacks/

Here is the code:

Messages.phtml

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'messages'">
<div data-bind="visible: isVisible(), click: RemoveMessage">
    <div role="alert" data-bind="foreach: { data: cookieMessages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'bounceInRight animated message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div class="text" data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            <div class="close" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="alert" data-bind="foreach: { data: messages().messages, as: 'message' }" class="messages">
        <div data-bind="attr: {
            class: 'bounceInRight animated message-' + message.type + ' ' + message.type + ' message',
            'data-ui-id': 'message-' + message.type
        }">
            <div class="text" data-bind="html: message.text"></div>
            <div class="close" style="display: none;" data-bind="visible: true"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div> 
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
  {
    "*": {
        "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
            "components": {
                    "messages": {
                        "component": "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
</script>
```

Messages.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'uiComponent',
'underscore',
'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, _, customerData,ko) {
'use strict';

return Component.extend({
    defaults: {
        cookieMessages: [],
        messages: [],
        selector: '.page.messages .message',
        listens: {
            isHidden: 'onHiddenChange'
        }
    },
    /** @inheritdoc */
    initialize: function () {
        this._super();

        this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
        this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
            disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
        });

        if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
            customerData.set('messages', {});
        } 

        $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
    },

    initObservable: function () {
        this._super()
            .observe('isHidden');

        return this;
    },

    RemoveMessage: function () {

        var el = $(this.selector);

        el.toggleClass('bounceInRight bounceOutRight');
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.hide()
        }, 2000);
    },

    isVisible: function () {
        return this.isHidden(!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages) || !_.isEmpty(this.cookieMessages));
    },

    onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
        var self = this;

        // Hide message block if needed
        console.log(isHidden);
        if (isHidden) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self.RemoveMessage();
            }, 5000);
        }
        // reseting variable
        this.isHidden(false);
    }

});

});
```

Comment: how can i make this in to a module?