# How to add count down hide all message in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, messages

I want to hide the message displayed in magento 2, after doing actions like add to cart, login, add wishlist, compare, error info, ... anyone have a good idea for my question? . Thanks everyone
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156852/84221

Comment: oh thank i let me check

Comment: @nhungo duc did you get any solution?

Comment: it does not display the message as normal the message is not displayed, it just shows the message frame and then hides

Comment: If you don't want to show page messages than you can hide it using css also

Comment: I want it to appear as normal and after about 5-10 seconds the message will be hidden

Comment: settimeout has been run, but text message is not displayed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @nhungoduc You can refer other answers too https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/321648/84221

Comment: thank you @RahulBarot